# A rating with three possible outcomes

Tags: probability

Thank you for reading this - I have no clue how to resolve the following problem.

I have a rating between 0 and 100 and three possible outcomes A, B and C.

Can anyone tell me how to work out the likelihood of an outcome dependent on the rating?

For example, let's say that I have a rating of 88 - how do I find out about the likelihood of the outcomes A, B and C based on previous outcomes as below?

100 - A,
32 - C,
99 - A,
2 - C,
11 - B,
46 - A,
88 - ?

Thank you for your help.

Ali

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  What's the connection between the rating and the outcome?  Is there any reason to imagine it isn;t purely random?

Comment: I see what you mean.  They aren't random - I think the best way to describe them would be the rating is for academic skill and the A, B and C are grades -so the higher the rating the more likely the outcome will be A. So the ratings in the 90's are nearly all A's and the bottom ratings are C's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a multinomial logistic regression model. Define
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x\end{pmatrix}; \quad
\boldsymbol{\beta}_a = \begin{pmatrix} \beta_{a0} \\ \beta_{a1}\end{pmatrix}; \quad 
\boldsymbol{\beta}_b = \begin{pmatrix} \beta_{b0} \\ \beta_{b1}\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbb{P}(G=A|x,\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b) = \frac{e^{\boldsymbol{\beta}_a \cdot \boldsymbol{x}}}{ 1 + e^{\boldsymbol{\beta}_a \cdot \boldsymbol{x}} + e^{\boldsymbol{\beta}_b \cdot \boldsymbol{x}} } ; \quad
\mathbb{P}(G=B|x,\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b) = \frac{e^{\boldsymbol{\beta}_b \cdot \boldsymbol{x}}}{ 1 + e^{\boldsymbol{\beta}_a \cdot \boldsymbol{x}} + e^{\boldsymbol{\beta}_b \cdot \boldsymbol{x}} } \; \quad
\end{align}
Now construct a likelihood function out of the six data points you have.
\begin{align}
L(\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b) &= \prod_{x \in \{100,99,46\}}\mathbb{P}(G=A|x,\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b) \prod_{x \in \{11\}}\mathbb{P}(G=B|x,\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b)
\prod_{x \in \{32,2\}}\left[1-\mathbb{P}(G=A|x,\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b)-\mathbb{P}(G=B|x,\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b)\right] \\
(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_a,\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_b) &= \arg \max L(\boldsymbol{\beta}_a,\boldsymbol{\beta}_b)
\end{align}
You need
$\mathbb{P}(G=A|88,\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_a,\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_b) $ and $\mathbb{P}(G=B|88,\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_a,\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_b) $.